# Load data skipping first column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import the data from...
ftp://ftp.bls.gov/pub/time.series/la/la.area_type

```
mysql -e"CREATE TABLE test.area_type (area_type_code varchar(100), state_wide varchar(100))"
mysql -e"load data local infile 'la.area_type' into table test.area_type fields terminated by '\t' ignore 1 lines;"
```

The above load data command does import the second column but fails to import the first column. What should be the correct load data command to import the data?

Comment: check your infile -- the execute commands are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The csv seems to be in dos format, try

```
dos2unix la.area_type
```

and re-import again